# toggle display in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to toggle visibility of signup and signin boxes if sign in and sign up buttons are clicked. I am trying to use only pure javascript.

I wrote simple html and javascript as below:

```
<div>
    <button class="signin">sign in</button><button class="signup">sign up</button>

    <div class="signin-box" style="display: none;">
        <form class="signin-form">
            <label>username<input></label><label>password<input></label><button type="submit">signin</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="signup-box" style="display: none;">
        <form class="signup-form">
            <label>username<input></label><label>password<input></label><button type="submit">signup</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript part:

```
var signupButton = document.getElementsByClassName('signup')[0];
var signinButton = document.getElementsByClassName('signin')[0];
var signupBox = document.getElementsByClassName('signup-box')[0];
var signipBox = document.getElementsByClassName('signin-box')[0];

console.log("box: ", signupBox, "button: ",signupButton);

var toggleVisible = function(item){
    if (item.style.display === 'none'){
        return item.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        return item.style.display = 'none';
    }
};

window.onload = function(){
    signupButton.onclick = toggleVisible(signupBox);
    signinButton.onclick = toggleVisible(signipBox);
};
```

The problem here is that the javascript toggleVisible is automatically activated even if i never clicked the buttons.

as a result, the signin-box and signup-box both gets display:block property.

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: The title is a bit misleading...what does this have to do with MongoDB?

Comment: @JasonCust  oops.. fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use a [standard](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) JavaScript method **addEventListener()** to attached `onclick` event listener to the button.
It has following advantages over different solution:

> You can attach an event handler to an element without overwriting existing event handlers.
>
> You can add many event handlers of the same type to one element, i.e
>   two "click" events.

In your code it will look like

```
window.onload = function(){
    signupButton.addEventListener("click", function() { toggleVisible(signupBox); });
    signinButton.addEventListener("click", function() { toggleVisible(signipBox); });
};
```

Current code invokes `toggleVisible(..)` method and assigns its result to the button attribute, which is not one would expect.

```
signupButton.onclick = toggleVisible(signupBox);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're calling the function, not passing it in. Just wrap your function call in an anonymous function:

```
signupButton.onclick = function() {
    toggleVisible(signupBox);
};
```

If you don't care about older browsers, you can also simplify your code a little if you put your JavaScript at the bottom of the `<body>` tag and add a rule to your CSS:

```
document.querySelector('.signup').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.signup-box').classList.toggle('hidden');
}, false);

document.querySelector('.signin').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.signin-box').classList.toggle('hidden');
}, false);
```

And the CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```